# Run Time Complexity vs Memory Complexity

Tags: python, time-complexity

I am using the following code:

```py
n = input()
data = input()

out = [0] * 10

for i in range(len(data)):


    if (data[i] == 'L'):
        for j in range(0, 10, 1):
            if (out[j] == 0):
                out[j] = 1
                break
    elif (data[i] == 'R'):
        for k in range(9, -1, -1):
            if (out[k]== 0):
                out[k] = 1
                break
    else:
        out[int(data[i])] = 0
    #print (str(data[i]) + " "+ str(out))
for x in out:
    print(x, end = '')
```

1. How do I determine the run time complexity for this program. I have read that for-loops take O(N), so would this program have that as its run time complexity?
2. How can I determine memory complexity for this program?

I have read online about these two concepts but I am unable to understand them, so sorry if these are basic questions.

Comment: `for` loops take however long it takes to iterate over its iterable. It's not always O(n). For example, `for x in itertools.product(data, data):` is O(n^2), ignoring what happens in the body of the loop, because there are O(n^2) elements in the cartesian product of `data` with itself.

Answer (score 0):

1. For loops do take O(N) time assuming everything inside the for loop takes O(1) time. This all depends. Your code in the for loop does run in constant time since it's always 10 actions, or the else. Your overall run time is o(n)
2. Memory complexity is usually called space complexity and that would be how much extra space you would need to take when running your code. Since you don't actually use any more arrays or space since everything is working in the out array, your space complexity is o(1). If, for example, you had another array that kept increasing in size, your space complexity would be o(n) since it grows with size.